# How to create progress indicator without filling color?

Tags: android, progress-bar

I have a viewpager with many images in my app. Below viewpager I need to show a progress indicator as shown in image. whenever the image is changed the dark blue part also will change its position accordingly. I am not sure which component to use here. Does it require a custom component? Will customizing progress bar work? Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: You can make a custom component for that. If not you can use libraries like this: https://github.com/tommybuonomo/dotsindicator

Comment: I dont want to use dots as the number of images can be more and that many dots will not look good. That is why slider kind of UI is there. To create custom component which component I have to use as the base?